# How to get RSS feed for custom field in post

Tags: rss

I have a list of post with different category, I am able to generate feed for a particular category,

But  I am trying to create a new custom field in post with the option selection box, If the particluar post is get selected with my custom field then the Feed need to generate based on the selection of custom field on that particular post

For Example : I am trying like this :  http://mydominain.com
/?post_type=post=customfield=rss_feed

Comment: Please use spell check before publishing your question. Thanks!

Comment: Is this question about website hosted on `wordpress.com`?

Comment: Thanks Brad & Rober add the changes , Is there any option to make this feed to get work.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I find solution to hide that particular category which is showed in front end, 
I use this code to hide the selected category front end : Function.php

```
add_filter('get_the_terms', 'hide_categories_terms', 10, 3);
```

function hide_categories_terms($terms, $post_id, $taxonomy){

```
// list of category slug to exclude, 
$exclude = array('computer');

if (!is_admin()) {
    foreach($terms as $key => $term){
        if($term->taxonomy == "category"){
            if(in_array($term->slug, $exclude)) unset($terms[$key]);
        }
    }
```

But any answer for how to get RSS feed by using custome field will be more appreciated .